# Trying to install a yeoman generator and i am getting a karma dependency issue

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner, yeoman-generator

Also If i try a reinstall of yeoman with `npm install -g yo` i get the same. Is there a way to start afresh?

```
$ npm i -g generator-assemble

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.6.2 wants karma@~0.10.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.12.8
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0a9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "generator-assemble"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/john/Desktop
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/john/Desktop/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```